# office 2003 frontpage with office 2010

Tags: microsoft-office, frontpage

A friend asked me if it is possible to install office2003 (she wants the 2003 version of frontpage for editing some legacy content created by that version) next to office 2010.
She has office 2010 professional plus so I hope it is okay to use a downgraded version license-wise.

How can one get a (localised aka. non-us) installer for such an outdated version?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Do a custom install, and tell it not to touch existing office files. It should ignore Office 2010 anyway.

Comment: This should work, but it would be better to have the older version installed first.